# Why Virginia changing the position of flower vase?

Tags: plot-explanation, entrapment

In *Entrapment (1999)*, Virginia is entered into building through window to steal **Rembrandt** portrait. After entering into the house, she changed the position of flower vase, why so ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

She's setting up an explanation of how the thief was able to get in to make herself look smarter.

There were no clues...so she **created one** by re-arranging the flowers to indicate that they were moved by the draught created when the window was opened.

[image]